# Python Looping and Web Scraping | BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Currently trying to loop the following web scraping...

My current problem is that I can only get the first footballer from the table **(I have the table HTML down below)** and not the full 10 players, my immediate thoughts are that the loop isn't working and I'm unsure where I'm going wrong. I'm using the BeautifulSoup Method of gathering the data.

***TD;DR My error is that only 1 player is appearing in my CSV file instead of the 10 players available from the HTML***

**Python Code**

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
 from urllib.request import Request
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

 my_url = "https://www.fctables.com/teams/stoke-194901/"

 #opening up connection , grabbing page
 uClient = uReq(my_url)
 page_html = uClient.read()
 uClient.close()

 #html parsing
 page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

 topScorers = page_soup.findAll("table",{"class":"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover stage-table table-condensed top_scores"})


 filename = "stokeGoals.csv"
 f = open(filename, "w")

 headers = "player, goal_scored, average_goal"

 f.write(headers)

 for topScorer in topScorers:
 #top 10 players who scored
 player = topScorer.a["title"]

#top 10 goalscorers for the team
goalpp = topScorer.findAll("div", {"class": "progress"})

#average goal per game
avg = topScorer.findAll("div", {"class": "label label-primary"})
avgpp = avg[0].text.strip()


print("player: " + player)
print("goal_scored: " + goalpp)
print("AVG: "+ avgpp)
    
f.write(player + "," +goalpp.replace("," , "|")+ "," + avgpp +"\n")

f.close()
```

**HTML Code** for the table/website I'm scraping data from

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover stage-table table-condensed top_scores">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th class="tl">Player</th>
        <th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Goals scores by player / Goals scores by his team">goals</th>
        <th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Average goals">
            Avg
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="212996">
            <img alt="Benik Afobe" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/s4/s4glg58a2350823d58/benik-afobe.png" width="20" /> <a href="/players/benik_afobe-212996/" title="Benik Afobe">Afobe</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">6</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.4</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="320050">
            <img alt="Thomas Ince" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/t5/t5ni157c703a92110b/thomas-ince.jpg" width="20" /> <a href="/players/thomas_ince-320050/" title="Thomas Ince">Ince</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 83.333333333333%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">5</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.6</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="308648">
            <img alt="Saido Berahino" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/po/poyhu58a234e0da106/saido-berahino.png" width="20" /> <a href="/players/saido_berahino-308648/" title="Saido Berahino">Berahino</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 66.666666666667%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">4</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.3</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="257340">
            <img alt="Joe Allen" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/6w/6w45558a234deae78e/joe-allen.png" width="20" /> <a href="/players/joe_allen-257340/" title="Joe Allen">Allen</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.4</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="234407">
            <img alt="Erik Pieters" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/et/et08558a234dd63b68/erik-pieters.png" width="20" /> <a href="/players/erik_pieters-234407/" title="Erik Pieters">Pieters</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.4</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="299368">
            <img alt="Peter Crouch" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/qp/qptn558a234df86f1f/peter-crouch.png" width="20" /> <a href="/players/peter_crouch-299368/" title="Peter Crouch">Crouch</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 33.333333333333%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.3</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="214479">
            <img alt="Bojan Krkic" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/pl/pleyv57eaedf0afeac/bojan-krkic.jpg" width="20" /> <a href="/players/bojan_krkic-214479/" title="Bojan Krkic">Krkic</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 33.333333333333%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.4</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="253114">
            <img alt="James McClean" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/gb/gbjmm58a234f55a560/james-mcclean.png" width="20" /> <a href="/players/james_mcclean-253114/" title="James McClean">McClean</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 16.666666666667%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="309022">
            <img alt="Sam Clucas" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/g7/g7dig58a234cb144a3/sam-clucas.png" width="20" /> <a href="/players/sam_clucas-309022/" title="Sam Clucas">Clucas</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 16.666666666667%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.3</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td class="tl psh" data-id="215724">
            <img alt="Bruno Martins Indi" class="img-circle" height="20" src="https://static.fctables.com/upload/images/20x20/hk/hkung58a234de0dfaa/bruno-martins-indi.png" width="20" /> <a href="/players/bruno_martins_indi-215724/" title="Bruno Martins Indi">Indi</a>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="55" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 16.666666666667%;">
                    <span class="goal_p">1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="label label-primary">0.2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are you getting a particular error? What is your question?

Comment: @PedroLobito sorry if I didn't specify specifically but my error is that my code is NOT looping and only displaying me the first player when I was hoping 9 more players from the HTML table above would also appear, if that makes sense to you

Comment: It's hard to see what your code is doing because the python code isn't indented correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the url as it is, you can try the following to fetch the required results:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.fctables.com/teams/stoke-194901/"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
for items in soup.select(".top_scores tbody tr"):
    name = items.select_one("td a[href^='/players/']").get("title")
    goal = items.select_one("td .goal_p").text
    avrg = items.select_one("td .label-primary").text
    print(name, goal, avrg)
```

Output you should get:

```
Benik Afobe 6 0.4
Thomas Ince 5 0.6
Saido Berahino 4 0.3
Joe Allen 3 0.4
Erik Pieters 3 0.4
Peter Crouch 2 0.3
Bojan Krkic 2 0.4
James McClean 1 0.1
Sam Clucas 1 0.3
Bruno Martins Indi 1 0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The webpage you specified, loads data via [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

You can grab the `html` directly from:

```
https://www.fctables.com/xml/table_participant/?template_id=&season_id=52%2C38%2C88&type_home=overall&type=top_score&lang_id=2&team_id=194901&limit=10
```

Through the above url, you can get all the information you need without the extra `html` *noise*, i.e.:

```
my_url = "https://www.fctables.com/xml/table_participant/?template_id=&season_id=52%2C38%2C88&type_home=overall&type=top_score&lang_id=2&team_id=194901&limit=10"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

_names = page_soup.findAll("img",{"class":"img-circle"})
_goals = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"goal_p"})
_avg = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"label label-primary"})
x = 0
for name in _names:
    name = name['alt']
    avg = _avg[x].get_text()
    goals = _goals[x].get_text()
    print(name, avg, goals)
    x+=1
```

---

```
Benik Afobe 0.4 6
Thomas Ince 0.6 5
Saido Berahino 0.3 4
Joe Allen 0.4 3
Erik Pieters 0.4 3
Peter Crouch 0.3 2
Bojan Krkic 0.4 2
James McClean 0.1 1
Sam Clucas 0.3 1
Bruno Martins Indi 0.2 1
```

---

Note:

Adjust the `url` values as needed, you can change `top_score`, `type`, `team_id`, `limit`, etc...